# Backspace adds character p instead of deleting characters

Tags: keyboard

I have an Asus K450J laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 and when I press backspace it types the character `p` and when I push the character `p`, nothing happens.

`stty a` gives the following:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

Comment: Is your keyboard's locale English? What's your keyboard layout set to?

Comment: Somehow they got fixed but now i have a new problem... Ctrl and Delete button don't release an event when i do: xev command.

Comment: please ask a new question.

Comment: already did. http://askubuntu.com/questions/713416/ctrl-delete-and-right-arrow-dont-work